# How To add a ChildWindow to MainWindow in WPF ,programatically?

Tags: wpf, wpf-extended-toolkit

I have a child window of type:

```
Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ChildWindow
```

and my main window is of type `System.Windows.Window`
How can I programmatically all my child window into my Main window?

Comment: The answer is actually on the Extended WPF Toolkit guide.

Comment: @Evangelink I found only this page in the documentation but it seems there is no mention about programmatically loading a childWindow http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ChildWindow&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Actually ,it says the main window type should be of type WindowContainer

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
in your xaml of main window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplicationTestChildWindow.Window2"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationTestChildWindow"
        xmlns:xceed="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
        xmlns:primitive="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Primitives;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <primitive:WindowContainer Name="cntr1">
        </primitive:WindowContainer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and in the code behind:

```
using System.Windows;
namespace WpfApplicationTestChildWindow
{
    public partial class Window2 : Window
    {
        public Window2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ChildWindow1 child1 = new ChildWindow1();
            cntr1.Children.Add(child1);
            child1.Show();
        }
    }
}
```